# How can I disable HealthKit integration in your app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, healthkit

I have an application to requestAuthorization to use HealthKit data into a tableView.

I use this code to ask permission to get HealthKit data:

```
- (IBAction)healthIntegrationButtonSwitched:(UISwitch *)sender {

    if (sender.isOn) {
        [[GSHealthKitManager sharedManager] requestAuthorization];
    } 
}

- (void)requestAuthorization {

    if ([HKHealthStore isHealthDataAvailable] == NO) {
        // If our device doesn't support HealthKit -> return.
        return;
    }

    NSArray *readTypes = @[[HKObjectType characteristicTypeForIdentifier:HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierDateOfBirth]];

    NSArray *writeTypes = @[[HKObjectType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass],
                            [HKObjectType workoutType]];

    [self.healthStore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:[NSSet setWithArray:writeTypes]
                                             readTypes:[NSSet setWithArray:readTypes] completion:nil];
}
```

Could I add to my healthIntegrationButtonSwitched function the other case when "if (sender.isOff) {" to cancel the permission accepted of HealthKit?

thanks!

Comment: Not sure why you would want to do this? As far as I'm aware it is not possible to de-authorize your permissions with HealthKit.. only suggestion would be to try an empty NSSet in the authorization method and see.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to de-authorize HealthKit access programmatically, but there's also no need to. When the switch is disabled you should just make sure to not query HealthKit anymore. Also the user can de-authorize your app in the Sources panel of the Health app if they have a privacy concern.